How to upload a Tv app on google play store
I am trying to upload a android tv app to google play store. But I am getting so many errors.

I am not able to find tv app screen shots session.
I am trying to upload a tv app not mobile app, in console its asking the phone and tablet screenshots also.
Please let me know step by step process of publishing the tv app.

I have uploaded one app but it got suspended due to multiple rejections.
